# Replace values within a URL in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a URL and I want to replace some contents(in the middle) of it with values present in a dictionary and save it in my local with the files name as the Key name in the dictionary. I have started coding but don't know how to proceed.

```
URL = 'http://api.trkd.thomsonreuters.com/api/streetevents/documents/61145274-DB5A-454D-9A31-E6D24E77A7B1/Transcript/Pdf.ashx'
```

The dictionary n has the below key,values:

```
Nio Inc Earnings Call 8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219
China Finance Online Co Ltd Earnings Call D166208D-CE51-46BF-819A-DB34CBF85A97
```

Code to save the pdf to my local

```
import requests

URL = 'http://api.trkd.thomsonreuters.com/api/streetevents/documents/61145274-DB5A-454D-9A31-E6D24E77A7B1/Transcript/Pdf.ashx'
r = requests.get(URL, stream=True, proxies=proxyDict)
with open('metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
 f.write(r.content)
```

I want to iterate over the dictionary 'n' and extract the value part from it and replace it in the URL.

E.g URL = 'http://api.trkd.thomsonreuters.com/api/streetevents/documents/61145274-DB5A-454D-9A31-E6D24E77A7B1/Transcript/Pdf.ashx' should change to

URL = 'http://api.trkd.thomsonreuters.com/api/streetevents/documents/8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219/Transcript/Pdf.ashx'

and download the pdf with name "Nio Inc Earnings Call.pdf" and then again replace the URL with the next Value in the dictionary and download it with its key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration with `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
import requests

URL = 'http://api.trkd.thomsonreuters.com/api/streetevents/documents/{}/Transcript/Pdf.ashx'
for k,v in n.items():
    r = requests.get(URL.format(v), stream=True, proxies=proxyDict)   #set value in URL
    with open('{}.pdf'.format(k), 'wb') as f:    #Set key as PDF name
        f.write(r.content)
```